# How do I use operator overload on an inherited class to match the base operator in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, operator-keyword

I have the following operator overload code:

```
public static Set operator+(Set left, Set right)
{
    Set sum=new Set(left.Capacity+right.Capacity);
    for (left.iterator_init(); !left.iterator_end(); left.iterator_next())
        sum.add_member(left.iterator_current());
    for (right.iterator_init(); !right.iterator_end(); right.iterator_next())
        sum.add_member(right.iterator_current());
    return sum;
}
```

Set is a class with an array of int numbers with Capcity length.

The function add_member inserts a number into the array.

I also have a class OrderedSet that inherits Set like this:

```
    class OrderedSet : Set
```

In this class I override "add_member" function to insert the numbers ascending.
Now I want to use the parent class (Set) operator+ overload the exact same way on OrderedSet, in a way where don't acctually have to rewrite the function again, but depend on the overload from the parent class.
**So if I wanna change the way I add two Sets or OrderedSets I will have to change the operator code ONLY on Set.**

I tried this:

```
    public static OrderedSet operator+(OrderedSet left, OrderedSet right):base(left,right)
    {

    }
```

But with no luck, I get syntax error.
So, what am I missing?

Comment: Your base operator+ returns `Set` and you can't convert it to `OrderedSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the neatest way to do this is to provide a `Set` constructor that creates a set by merging two sets

```
protected Set(Set left, Set right)
{
    this.Capacity = left.Capacity + right.Capacity;
    for (left.iterator_init(); !left.iterator_end(); left.iterator_next())
        this.add_member(left.iterator_current());
    for (right.iterator_init(); !right.iterator_end(); right.iterator_next())
        this.add_member(right.iterator_current());
}
```

which you can reuse in your `OrderedSet` class

```
protected OrderedSet(OrderedSet left, OrderedSet right)
    : base(left, right)
{

}
```

and then reuse both in the add overrides:

```
public static Set operator +(Set left, Set right)
{
    return new Set(left, right);
}

public static OrderedSet operator +(OrderedSet left, OrderedSet right)
{
    return new OrderedSet(left, right);
}
```

That way if the shared "concatenate two sets" logic changes you only have to change it in one place, and if you want `OrderedSet` to use its own logic you can stop calling the `base` constructor.

Comment: It almost worked perfectly except for that fact that the new_member function that Set uses is also used for OrderedSet.

Comment: Nvm, I used virtual and override and all is well!

Comment: Do you mean `add_member`? In theory you can make that method `virtual` on `Set` and `override` on `OrderedSet` and the constructor will call the correct version, but also in theory it's a bad idea to call an `override` method from a constructor :( (It's OK as long as you know what you're doing, I suppose.)

Answer (score 2):

The error is generated as the methods for operators are static.  It is not possible to use the base keyword in a static method.

As such it's not possible using the `:` - It would be possible to call the base class directly within the method body however.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static int Jump(int height)
    {
        return height * 10;
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public static int Jump(int height)
    {
        return Foo.Jump(height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Set version, but since it returns Set you will have to convert your Set to an OrderedSet before you can return.

```
public static OrderedSet operator+(OrderedSet left, OrderedSet right)
{
  Set mySet = (Set)left+(Set)right;
  return SoSomethingToConvertYourSetToAnOrderedSet(mySet);
}
```